# Is there a notion of similarity for shapes on the sphere?

Tags: geometry

There are similar shapes in the plane, such as similar triangles. So is there a similar shape on the sphere? For example, is a great circle similar to a small circle on a sphere? I think great circles and small circles are similar, so there are similar shapes on the sphere. So as shown in the figure, are there similar two sides on the sphere?

[image: The shape of both sides of a sphere]

Here is my opinion:

[image]

Can two rectangles of different sizes be similar on a plane? Obviously, rectangles can be similar. Under what conditions are they similar?

1. The proportion of their corresponding sides is equal;
2. Their corresponding angles are equal.

These two conditions must be met at the same time.

Squares are also similar because they meet both conditions 1 and 2.

The conditions for the similarity of rectangle and triangle are not exactly the same. Although, we can think of each rectangle as consisting of two triangles.

In the plane, two regular polygons with the same number of sides are similar because they meet the requirements of conditions 1 and 2 at the same time.

We can think that any two circles are regular polygons with the same number of sides, so any two circles are similar. Because they meet both conditions 1 and 2. (their corresponding angles are all π).

If we take two points on each circle, we get some shapes with two sides. Can these shapes be similar? Obviously they can be similar. As long as they meet the requirements of condition 1 (their corresponding angles are π).

Can two shapes formed by closed curves be similar? I think they can be similar, and the conditions of judgment are similar, but the judgment is more complicated.

Are two circles similar on a sphere? Obviously they are similar. Because they meet both conditions 1 and 2.

On a sphere, are the two shapes shown in the figure similar (they are composed of arcs)? Obviously they can be similar as long as they meet the requirements of conditions 1 and 2 at the same time.

All is exploration. I'm not sure what I said is right. I hope you can talk about your knowledge.

Comment: Depends on how you define "similar". But at the very least, you have _congruent_ shapes, and those ought to be considered similar no matter how you look at it.

Comment: What you refer to as "two sides" is called a *bigon*.

Comment: Great circles are similar to smaller circles only in the 3-space in which the surface is embedded. They are not similar in the surface itself; for instance, only the great circle is a geodesic.

Comment: And while some folks would say that these 'shapes' are problematic, I say let bigons be bigons.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier a bigon

Comment: @TonyK As other researchers ask: are two small circles on a sphere similar? They are not geodesics.

Comment: @z.qmpx That's what I wrote, yes.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You mean that small circles on a sphere are similar.

Comment: @z.qmpx No. Please read the answers.

Answer (score 6):

Similarity can be tricky business.

Instead of the broad category of "shapes", first consider triangles.

In Euclidean geometry, "similar" triangles have the "same shape", a notion we clarify with the properties

> 1. Corresponding angles are congruent.
> 2. Corresponding sides are proportional.

Conveniently, property (1) implies (2), and vice-versa. Perhaps because angle-congruence is easier to check, "angles are congruent" is sometimes taken as *the* defining characteristic of similar triangles, with "sides are proportional" being a useful consequence. It doesn't seem to matter. Of course, we when consider "similar polygons", the logical equivalence breaks: squares and, say, golden rectangles have congruent angles, but their sides aren't proportional; conversely, squares and non-square rhombi have proportional sides, but their angles aren't congruent. "Same shape"-ness for polygons in general requires *both* (1) and (2).

Defining "same shape"-ness for curves is a little more nuanced, since we can't compare angles or sides directly. (We can get technical and establish a "similarity transformation" involving a dilation.) Nevertheless, it's "obvious" that all circles have the "same shape", so if the descriptor "similar" applies to *any* figures, it certainly applies to *them*.

---

On the sphere, triangles already drive a wedge between (1) and (2). If corresponding sides are proportional, but not congruent, the corresponding angles *are not* congruent. (Specifically, larger sides make for larger angles. For example, consider a tiny-tiny equilateral triangle, whose angles are close to $60^\circ$ each, and the equilateral triangle joining the North, "East", and "West" Poles, whose angles are $90^\circ$.) Contrariwise, if corresponding angles are congruent, then *the corresponding sides are congruent*; "Angle-Angle-Angle" is a *congruence* pattern! This phenomenon can be summarized as

> "There are no similar triangles in spherical geometry."

which is shorthand for "There are no similar triangles ---in the sense of (1) and (2)--- that aren't fully congruent triangles, so we have no use for the term 'similar'".

But what about circles?

In the vague sense of "same shape"-ness, then all circles on the sphere *should be* considered "similar". In the technical sense of "similarity transformation"-ability, too: simply align centers with an isometry and apply an appropriate dilation. Case closed!

And yet ...

On the (unit-radius) sphere, a spherical circle with radius $\theta$ *as measured along the surface of the sphere* is a plane circle with radius $\sin\theta$ *as measured on the plane containing the circle*; such a circle has circumference $C = 2\pi\sin\theta$. But, then, a circle with (surface) radius $2\theta$ has circumference $2\pi\sin 2\theta \neq 2C$: *doubling the radius **does not** double the circumference*; indeed, the circumference could get smaller! Likewise for other scale factors (apart from $1$).

This isn't the kind of behavior we've come to expect from "same shape" figures in the Euclidean plane. In light of this situation, we recognize that our (1) and (2) are actually insufficient to capture the entirety of our expectations. We find that a refinement is in order:

> - 2'. Corresponding *lengths* are proportional.

Here, "length" isn't limited to just sides. It applies to medians, altitudes, arbitrary cevians, midpoint segments, etc, for triangles; diagonals of quadrilaterals and polygons; perimeters for everything; radii and circumferences for circles; and on and on and on. Here again, Euclidean geometry spoils us: figures that satisfy (1) and (2) ---and/or admit a similarity transformation--- automatically satisfy (2'); it's a freebie. Spherical geometry, however, reveals (2') to be a *stronger* condition of "same shape"-ness; a condition that spherical circles do not satisfy *unless they are fully congruent*.

---

In the context of $(2')$, we find that, apart from segments,

> "There are no [non-congruent] similar figures *at all* in spherical geometry."

If you choose to reject $(2')$ as a requirement, then arbitrary circles might reasonably be called "similar", but in a way that's almost-no help to further investigation and that's almost-certain to cause confusion. It would be better to apply a different descriptor ("quasi-similar"?).

Comment: Are squares of different sizes similar?In the plane, circles are similar to circles. Their similarity ratio is not the ratio of circle diameter, but the ratio of circumference. A circle with a circumference of 1 and a circle with a circumference of 2 have a similar ratio of 0.5.

Comment: In the plane, squares are similar; on the sphere ... well, there aren't "squares", *per se*: no quadrilateral has four right angles. (Angle-sums are always greater than $360^\circ$.) There are "equiangular rhombi", but if angles match, then sides match (making them congruent), and if sides are only proportional (but not congruent) then angles aren't congruent. Again, there are no "similar" figures that aren't fully "congruent", making "similar" an unnecessary descriptor. (continued)

Comment: (cont'd) As for circles: In the plane, a similarity ratio applies to *all corresponding lengths* ... circumferences, radii, chords that make inscribed septagons, tangents that make circumscribed 211-gons, etc, etc, etc. On the sphere, the ratio of circumferences applies to *no other corresponding lengths*, apart from arcs (semi-circles, quarter-circles, etc). The ratio of circumferences is a "similarity ratio" in such an exceedingly-weak sense that the term shouldn't be used; just say "circumference ratio", because that's all it is.

Comment: Before I engage further: Are you the Math.SE user formerly known as [E.wei](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/521667/e-wei)?

Comment: I should've known. I'm done here.

Comment: My work is a kind of exploration, and exploration inevitably makes mistakes. But in order to find the truth, we must explore.

Comment: Can two rectangles of different sizes be similar on a plane? Obviously, rectangles can be similar. Under what conditions are they similar?
1. The proportion of their corresponding sides is equal;
2. Their corresponding angles are equal.
These two conditions must be met at the same time.

Squares are also similar because they meet both conditions 1 and 2.
The conditions for the similarity of rectangle and triangle are not exactly the same. Although, we can think of each rectangle as consisting of two triangles.

Comment: In the plane, two regular polygons with the same number of sides are similar because they meet the requirements of conditions 1 and 2 at the same time.
We can think that any two circles are regular polygons with the same number of sides, so any two circles are similar. Because they meet both conditions 1 and 2. (their corresponding angles are all π).
If we take two points on each circle, we get some shapes with two sides. Can these shapes be similar? Obviously they can be similar. As long as they meet the requirements of condition 1 (their corresponding angles are π).

Comment: Can two shapes formed by closed curves be similar? I think they can be similar, and the conditions of judgment are similar, but the judgment is more complicated.
Are two circles similar on a sphere? Obviously they are similar. Because they meet both conditions 1 and 2.
On a sphere, are the two shapes shown in the figure similar (they are composed of arcs)? Obviously they can be similar as long as they meet the requirements of conditions 1 and 2 at the same time.
All is exploration. I'm not sure what I said is right. I hope you can talk about your knowledge.

Comment: @Blue Don't you wish there was a way to mute notifications on comment threads, the way one can on Twitter?

Comment: @Rahul: Absolutely ... and blocking specific users, as well, especially when they use multiple names; it's hard to consciously keep track of whom to ignore. (I suspect that "z.qmpx" is both ["E.wei"](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/521667) and ["enbin zheng"](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/503250). fleablood's interaction with "zheng" after [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2543157/409) mirrors various encounters of mine with "E.wei" and now "z.qmpx" ... although I'm not sure the other personas have ever admitted "I'm not sure what I said is right". Progress?)

Comment: (That certainly feels like a thin crack of light in the darkness.)

Answer (score 5):

As was mentioned in the comments, it depends on what you are willing to call "similar".

One reasonable option would be to take into account the curvature of the sphere, since it is an intrinsic feature. In the plane, it makes no difference, since it is everywhere flat, but when you compare similar triangles you do take into account the angles, which is a geometric feature as well.

On the sphere, making a triangle "bigger" will also automatically change its angles, because it changes the total curvature of the piece of surface enclosed by the shape. So all in all the natural notion of similarity is much more rigid on the sphere and you end up with geometric figures being similar only if they are actually isometric, in most cases.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. In fact the existence of similar but not congruent triangles is equivalent to Euclid's parallel postulate.

Comment: @EthanBolker Good point. A related piece of blog: [chasing the parallel postulate](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/chasing-the-parallel-postulate/).

Answer (score -2):

It should not be said that the great circle is geodesic, so we think that the great circle and the small circle are not similar. Because we can also ask: are two small circles with different diameters similar? When the diameter increases, the small circle can coincide with the great circle, and the small circle can coincide with the small circle. So I think: on the sphere, any two circles are similar, whether they are great circles and small circles, or small circles and small circles. Only in this way can our geometric theory be unified, otherwise our geometric theory will be split.

Comment: Your thought is formatted by Euclidean ideas. What is the similarity (a map $T:S^2\to S^2$) that brings a circle of some diameter to a circle of another diameter? What is so natural about this map that it deserves to be called a similarity? What does it do to other shapes?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier There is a similar ratio between two circles, one of which will become the other through transformation. Is that what similarity means?

Comment: The reason that mathematicians don't use your idea for the similarity of circles is that the dimensions don't change _proportionally_.  There is not a complete "similar ratio between them". If the circumference of the large circle is double that of the small circle then  the big radius (when measured _on the sphere_) won't be twice the small radius. You can continue to call them similar if that's how you want to use the word, but people who study mathematics will continue to require that _all_ the linear dimensions change with  the same ratio. @Blue makes this point in their answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker You should also know that plane geometry is different from spherical geometry, so it is not exactly the same when talking about similarity. For example, two points in the plane determine a straight line, and three points on the sphere determine a straight line. It can be seen that spherical geometry is different from plane geometry.